# Swift generic variable

Tags: ios, generics, swift

I have a protocol, and I'd like to have a variable of type UIViewController implementing mu protocol. If I try to do something like:

```
var delegate:UIViewController<BouncingMenuDelegate>?
```

I receive error that UIViewController is a non-generic type. Then the question is being how to access the model we used in Objective-C for accessing delegates? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare variable type like that in Swift.

The easiest way to solve your problem is adding `UIViewController` methods/properties to `BouncingMenuDelegate` requirement:

```
@objc protocol BouncingMenuDelegate {
    // Delegate methods
    func boudcingMenu(bouncingMenu:BouncingMenu, didSelectItemAtIndex index:Int)

    // required methods/properties from UIViewController 
    var view:UIView { get }
    var navigationController:UINavigationController? { get }
    func presentViewController(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
}

class BouncingMenu:UIView {
    weak var delegate:BouningMenuDelegate?
}
```

Comment: While it may be easy at first to do this. It's a hack and that should be noted.

Answer (score 0):

If the class implements a protocol you don't care about which class it actually is. This should work:

```
var delegate: BouncingMenuDelegate?
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and it does not work. Actually, I need to access a UIViewController's instance that implements my protocol.