# Concrete class type conforming to protocol in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, types, protocols, declaration

I need to declare a variable with type `UIViewController` that conforms to a custom protocol I made. Normally, I would do this in ObjC:

```
UIViewController<MyProtocol> *thingie;
```

But, I have no idea how to accomplish that in swift.

---

I'm just casting the object for now, till something useful shows up:

```
let conformingObject = viewController as MyProtocol
```

Comment: Does it matter whether or not the object actually is a `UIViewController`?

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, I access the `UIViewController` methods as well as the protocol methods.

Comment: Are there objects you want to conform to `MyProtocol` that are not `UIViewController`s?

Comment: @nhgrif Yeah, of course, otherwise I'd use a subclass. Some are `UINavigationController`s, others `UICollectionViewController`s.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift generic variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443153/swift-generic-variable)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26401778/swift-how-can-i-declare-a-variable-of-a-specific-type-that-conforms-to-one-or-m

Answer (score 1):

You may achieve something similar by using generics. Something like this:

```
class SomeClass<T where T: UIViewController, T: MyProtocol> {
    var thingie: T
}
```