# Applying Generics to Variables and Functions - Swift

Tags: ios, generics, swift, protocols, nsobject

I'm trying to use generics in swift in order to initialise variables within my Vector3D class. However, upon assigning the protocol 'Number' to my variable (to make it either a Double or Float) I get the following error:

> Protocol 'Number' can only be used as a generic constraint because it
>   has Self or associated type requirements

```
public protocol Number {
    func +(l: Self, r: Self) -> Self
}    
extension Double : Number {}
extension Float  : Number {}


class Vector3D: NSObject {

    var xCord: Number
    var yCord: Number
    var zCord: Number


    func Vector3D(x: [Number], y: [Number], z: [Number]) {
        self.xCord = x
        self.yCord = y
        self.zCord = z
    }
}
```

My questions is then, how do you apply generics to variables in swift and in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add generics to variables in Swift as already shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26443153/swift-generic-variable), but you can add generics to a function like that:

```
func swapTwoValues<T>(inout a:T, inout b:T){
  let temporaryA = a
  a = b
  b = temporaryA
}
```

[Check the apple Documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID181)

Answer (score 1):

The generic is created here `<T>`. It's like a variable for Types. You can change the T to anything you want as long as it's not used as a Type somewhere. The constraint bit is `: Number`. It constraints the type of T to the types that adhere to the Number Protocol.

```
func Vector3D<T: Number>(x: [T], y: [T], z: [T]) {
    self.xCord = x
    self.yCord = y
    self.zCord = z
}
```

As stated in the other answer, Variables and Constants cannot be of type Generic.