# Workarounds for generic variable in Swift

Tags: swift, variables, generics, tuples, type-alias

So I have a typealias tuple

```
public typealias MyTuple<T> = (key: T, value: String)
```

In my ViewController, I want to declare an array of MyTuple with generic data type as I still don't know the type for key yet. However, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28160436/7113238) it is impossible to have a generic-type variable in Swift. There are other workarounds as follows but I don't like either of them. Anyone has better ideas?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var array1 = [MyTuple<T>]() // compile error of course

    var array2 = [MyTuple<Any>]() // no point as I'd use `Any` for MyTuple

    func getArray<T>(array: Array<MyTuple<T>>) -> Array<MyTuple<T>> {
        return array // not a good approach
    }
}
```

Comment: So the issue is that VC will determine the actual `T` type at runtime and you can't declare array `[MyTuple<ConcreteType>]`  because of that, right?

Comment: @VadimPopov The issue is that I have another view controller (vcA) which will call ViewController and pass data to MyTuple array at some point. By then I will know what would be type of the key, but not now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something similar using a protocol for the array declaration and base methods that are not dependent on the data type of the key:

```
protocol KeyValueArray
{
   associatedtype KeyType
   var array:[(key:KeyType,value:String)] { get set }
}

extension KeyValueArray
{
   var array:[(key: KeyType, value:String)] { get {return []} set { } }
}

class ViewController:UIViewController,KeyValueArray 
{
   // assuming this is like an "abstact" base class 
   // that won't actually be instantiated.
   typealias KeyType = Any   

   // you can implement base class functions using the array variable
   // as long as they're not dependent on a specific key type.
}

class SpecificVC:ViewController
{
   typealias KeyType = Int 
   var array:[(key:Int,value:String)] = []
}
```

I'm assuming that, at some point the concrete instances of the view controller subclasses will have an actual type for the keys

Comment: Best idea so far. Do you know how to update the typealias KeyType without having to subclass the ViewController?

Comment: That would require some form of type erasure and would essentially result in an array variable that is as permissive as (key:Any, value:String).  Perhaps a more detailed description of what you are trying to achieve could help us make a better suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, in that case @zoul's suggestion works for me. The only disadvantage is I cannot extend ViewController.

Comment: Figured out it won't work with delegate either, and I don't want to use closure completions so I posted a new question as suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44490152/7113238

Answer (score 5):

I think the usual way to solve this is to “push” the type decision higher up the dependency chain, to the view controller:

```
class ViewController<T>: UIViewController {
    var array: [MyTuple<T>]
}
```

That makes sense, since you would probably think about the controller as a “foo controller”, where “foo” is the concrete value of `T`. (A “pet controller”, a “product controller,” etc.) But of course you can’t create an instance of the array until you know the concrete type.

Comment: I've thought about a generic view controller but if I want to extend my ViewController later, wouldn't that be impossible?