# Generic view controller won't work with delegate and extension

Tags: ios, swift, generics, delegates, type-alias

I already posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44469650/7113238) but it was not clear about what I want. As @AlainT suggested, I filed a new one.

I have a typealias tuple

```
public typealias MyTuple<T> = (key: T, value: String)
```

A protocol:

```
public protocol VCADelegate: class {
    associatedtype T
    func didSelectData(_ selectedData: MyTuple<T>)
}
```

A view controller (VCA) with a table view

```
class VCA<T>: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var dataList = [MyTuple<T>]()
    weak var delegate: VCADelegate? // Error: can only be used as a generic constraint    

    // ...

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelectData(dataList[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

In another view controller (VCB), I create a VCA and pass through a dataList

```
func callVCA() {
    let vcA = VCA<String>()
    vcA.dataList = [(key: "1", value:"Value 1"),
                    (key: "2", value:"Value 2")]
}
```

What I want to do is to have a dataList without knowing key's data type in VCA. Only when VCB calls VCA then I know the data type of the key. Creating a generic view controller will cause an issue with delegate. Any way to solve this problem without having to change to closure completion?

The other issue of using a generic view controller is I can't extend it. Any idea?

Comment: "What I want to do is to have a dataList without knowing key's data type in VCA. Only when VCB calls VCA then I know the data type of the key." It's unclear what you mean here. If VCB knows the associated type of VCA (in order to call it,) as you say, then how does it not know the type? What is the "issue with delegate?" Nothing here seems to store VCA as a property; is it only a local variable? (If so, what is the calling code? It seems you've hard-coded T==String; so where don't you know this?)

Comment: The issue with delegate is right in my comment: "can only be used as a generic constraint ..."

Comment: What I mean is in VCA, I don't know data type of MyTuple's key. Only VCB knows it. From VCB, I could either pass String, Int or whatever data type to the MyTuple's key. "Nothing here seems to store VCA as a property", if you are confused of the last block of code. I've putted it in a function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a standard type-erasure situation, though in this particular case I'd just pass a closure (since there's only one method).

Create a type eraser instead of a protocol:

```
public struct AnyVCADelegate<T> {
    let _didSelectData: (MyTuple<T>) -> Void
    func didSelectData(_ selectedData: MyTuple<T>) { _didSelectData(selectedData)}
    init<Delegate: VCADelegate>(delegate: Delegate) where Delegate.T == T {
        _didSelectData = delegate.didSelectData
    }
}
```

Use that instead of a delegate:

```
class VCA<T>: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource UITableViewDelegate {

    var dataList = [MyTuple<T>]()
    var delegate: AnyVCADelegate<T>?

    // ...

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelectData(dataList[indexPath.row])
    }
}
```

Your underlying problem is that protocols with associated types are not proper types themselves. They're only type constraints. If you want to keep it a PAT, that's fine, but then you have to make `VCA` generic over the Delegate:

```
class VCA<Delegate: VCADelegate>: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var dataList = [MyTuple<Delegate.T>]()
    weak var delegate: Delegate?

    init(delegate: Delegate?) {
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init(coder: NSCoder) { super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil) }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        delegate?.didSelectData(dataList[indexPath.row])
    }
}

class VCB: UIViewController, VCADelegate {

    func didSelectData(_ selectedData: MyTuple<String>) {}

    func callVCA() {
        let vcA = VCA(delegate: self)
        vcA.dataList = [(key: "1", value:"Cinnamon"),
                        (key: "2", value:"Cloves")]
    }
}
```

As a rule, protocols with associated types (PATs) are a very powerful, but special-purpose tool. They aren't a replacement for generics (which are a general purpose tool).

For this particular problem, though, I'd probably just pass a closure. All a type eraser is (usually) is a struct filled with closures. (Some day the compiler will probably just write them for us, and much of this issue will go away and PATs will be useful in day-to-day code, but for now it doesn't.)

Comment: Thanks Rob for the detailed answer. I'm trying to wrap my head around type erasure, will get back to check your answer again.

Comment: A couple of resources: http://robnapier.net/erasure introduces type erasers. https://www.dotconferences.com/2016/01/rob-napier-beyond-crusty-real-world-protocols Talk on replacing complex protocols with simpler structs.